# multiple default values for function arguments Python

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing

If I had a class with a function like the following and I wanted to have two variables that had default values:

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, var1=1, var2=2)
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
```

How could I create an instance of this class and change `var2`'s value but not `var1`'s?

```
a = item(#Leave var1 alone, but set var2 to 'hello')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just instantiate it like:

```
# leave var1 as default
a = item(var2='hello')

# leave var2 as default
a = item(var1='hey')

# overwrite both var1 and var2
a = item(var1='hey', var2='hello')

# use both defaults
a = item()
```

The thing to note in your example in the comment is you *must* now provide a `var1` since it has no default.  So `item(var1=1, var3=2)` and `item(1, var3=2)` would both work, while `item(var3=2)` would not.  Also keyword arguments must come last when there are arguments without default values, so `item(var3=2, 1)` would also not work but `item(var3=2, var1=1)` would.

Comment: What if I had `def __init__(self, var1, var2=2, var3=3)`? Would it be the same?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same.  Try it for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use named parameters when instantiating:

```
a = item(var2=42)
```

This would leave `var1` to its default value of `1`, but set `var2` to 42.

---

The following script shows this in action:

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, var1=1, var2=2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

a = item()
print a.var1
print a.var2

b = item(var2=42)
print b.var1
print b.var2
```

The output of that is, as desired:

```
1
2
1
42
```